# How to control CPU frequency

Tags: cpu

On Lenovo T400 and Ubuntu 10.10, I am using CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor 2.30.0 on the panel to show and control CPU frequency.

My CPU frequency by default will change according to load. But I want to make CPU work at the lowest level and so I choose 800 MHz in CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor. After a few seconds, however, it automatically changes back to Powersave or Performance mode which has automatic adjustment to CPU frequency.

I was wondering how to actually make CPU work at the lowest level? Thanks!

PS:
On Acer Aspire 5000 and ubuntu 8.10, I can use CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor to control CPU frequency as I wish.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Possibly this is relevant : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cpufreqd/+bug/344252

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf 
sudo rcconf
```

Search for

`ondemand`

option and disable(un-check the check-box) it using space-bar.

Comment: @Tim .. Usefull answer?

Comment: @Ilias el Matani: Thanks! It doesn't solve the problem, as CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor still shows the freq of one CPU is set to "Performance" instead of "Ondemand" and is automatically change, while that of the other CPU is fixed at 800 MHz.

Comment: Looks like I can only control frequency of one of the two CPUs via CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor.

Comment: I think the question is not clear for me. If you disable 'ondemand' in rcconf the frequency of your CPU is not automatically being changed?

Comment: If I uncheck 'ondemand' in rcconf, the frequency of my CPUs is still automatically being changed.

Comment: Check "acpi-cpufreq" and "cpufreq_ondemand" in rc.conf. Otherwise try cpufreq-set -g ondemand

Answer (score 0):

`man cpufreq-set`. Quick answer:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -r -d MINIMUM-FREQUENCY -u MAXIMUM-FREQUENCY
```

You might try the exact command:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -r -d 800MHz -u 1GHz
```