# how to reducing cpu frequency (I have spent over 2 hours trying)

Tags: cpufreq

I want to reduce my CPU frequency to less then the original

```
johnul@johnul-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               2594.070
CPU max MHz:           3200.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
BogoMIPS:              5188.14
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts

johnul@johnul-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
cat: '/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq': No such file or directory

johnul@johnul-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
```

that is my output its useful to solve the problem 
i want my CPU to be 2.00GHz or maybe 1.50GHz to reduce the heat I live in a hot area

how to do that ?

I have seen this link [How to control CPU frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26063/how-to-control-cpu-frequency) but nothing that I can apply

I have searched a lot and I am tired now, my heavy useage temps is 80C to 85C sometime it went to 90C

I heave fixed this problem in windows very easily

Comment: There are lots of options in this area. I've found great success with `thermald` and `ltp` packages installed with default settings. My laptop temps used to be like yours but now hover around 50c.

Comment: PLEASE tell me how to do it or give me a link

Comment: basically `sudo apt-get install thermald` and `sudo apt-get install tlp`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872

Comment: E: Unable to locate package apt-get
   E: Unable to locate package install

Comment: my main question is how to set the CPU frequency manually permanently to 2.00GHz or 1.50GHz ? and can i use paowersavig mode to make it in a (1.20GHz to 2.00GHz) range ?

Comment: Are you sure this is a CPU-clock problem and not a problem of the cooling/fan (I.e. dust, etc) ? What version of Ubuntu are you on ?

Comment: @JohnAdamHIG `thermald` is very good at keeping clock frequencies low now although at the expense of higher CPU %. What kernel version are you using? Older kernels don't seem to good as the newest ones.

Comment: my is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, there is not problem in cooling stuff @Robert Riedl and thermaled is cannot be installed last time i checked (which is yesterday) but ill check today againas well(i know its not a windows that probles fixed by it self but ill to today again)

Comment: by the way it runs fin on windows while using throttlestop

Comment: GOD DAMMIT I AM TRYING TO USE THIS SHIT SINCE 2014 SOMEONE JUST GIVE ME STEP TO STEP ONE HOW TO FUCKING  SET THE CPU ON LOWER FREQUENCY PLEASE ,BE HUMAN AND GIVE ME A GOOD NOT OUT OF DATE NOT NOT SOME FAR  AWAY STEPS

Comment: i need this shit for my collage so please someone help me

Comment: If [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/285681/349837) is overwhelming, just reduce frequency with `indicator-cpufreq`, disable Bluetooth, and reduce brightness. Also you have `cpufreq-selector` (download first `gnome-applets` package).

Answer (score 0):

The Core family CPUs of that generation have automatic clock frequency management.  Current driver/microcode versions for the generation you're running have exactly two settings: Performance, or Powersaver.  Both will increase frequency as needed for load; the difference is in how aggressively the frequency is scaled back.

FWIW, I have a laptop with a Core i5-3520M that routinely runs one core above 100 C and the other above 90 C; it slows itself down (to as low as 350 MHz) as needed to manage temperature (I'm currently trying to work with the refurbisher to see if this is endemic to the model or something that can be corrected).

The only hope you have for manual clock reduction, whether for thermal management, performance simulation, or whatever, is underclocking from the motherboard -- and that's a BIOS/hardware function, and would be off topic here (try SuperUser.SE?).

The other alternatives are the standards, make sure cooling intakes are clear, internal air pathways are clean, and consider obtaining a laptop cooler pad (these use a Peltier chip system to feed precooled air into the computer's air intakes).  If not a laptop, you might also check that your thermal grease is fresh, your CPU fan is operating correctly, heat sink is not clogged with dust, and if necessary, considering upgrading your cooling solution.

Comment: the standards are clear but in BIOS there is no such option like that so? how to do it manually that is my question

Comment: If there isn't a BIOS option to change clock speed (and there isn't likely to be on either a laptop or a consumer desktop motherboard), that option is closed, short of a motherboard replacement.

Comment: i have reduced it on windows useing throttlestop

Comment: its a laptop man @Zeiss Ikon